# iwlwifi drivers not loading for ax200 in MX linux

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, intel, firmware

Kernel is 5.8, wifi driver is the intel iwlwifi version for ax200 requiring a kernel of at least 5.1 and the wifi card appears in lspci -k but nothing I've tried is working as I can't find any documentation from intel surrounding this or any other thread someone has asked, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
sudo dmesg | grep wifi outputs:

```
[    8.389266] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode (-2) 
[    8.389279] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2 
[    8.588769] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode 
[    8.588779] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver 
[    8.588789] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22 
[    8.588792] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM 
[    8.588793] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0 
[    8.589074] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm 
[    8.589099] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2) 
[    9.044347] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340 
[    9.220725] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: a8:7e:ea:ed:72:a9 
[   28.267523] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5b22, CPU2 Status: 0x3 
[   28.267561] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80480218 
[   28.267585] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104 
[   28.267603] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired. 
[   28.267680] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   28.267736] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6 
[   28.267794] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode 
[   28.267856] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL     
[   28.267903] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0 
[   28.267922] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1 
[   28.267942] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004FA34A | branchlink2 
[   28.267961] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink1 
[   28.267979] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink2 
[   28.267999] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | data1 
[   28.268016] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2 
[   28.268033] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3 
[   28.268049] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time 
[   28.268068] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00007F4D | tsf low 
[   28.268085] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi 
[   28.268102] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1 
[   28.268120] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000DB62 | time gp2 
[   28.268138] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type 
[   28.268159] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | uCode version major 
[   28.268179] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | uCode version minor 
[   28.268214] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version 
[   28.268250] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version 
[   28.268288] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd 
[   28.268322] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0 
[   28.268355] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1 
[   28.268388] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2 
[   28.268421] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3 
[   28.268454] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4 
[   28.268506] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id 
[   28.268548] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | wait_event 
[   28.268585] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control 
[   28.268622] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration 
[   28.268659] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid 
[   28.268689] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match 
[   28.268708] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel 
[   28.268727] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp 
[   28.268745] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler 
[   28.268806] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   28.268843] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7 
[   28.268882] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x201000A3 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT 
[   28.268922] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1 
[   28.268961] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2 
[   28.269000] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0086AC0 | umac interruptlink1 
[   28.269041] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2 
[   28.269082] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1 
[   28.269834] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2 
[   28.270616] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3 
[   28.271341] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major 
[   28.272018] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor 
[   28.272767] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000DB54 | frame pointer 
[   28.273448] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886BF8 | stack pointer 
[   28.274127] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd 
[   28.274851] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg 
[   28.275533] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers: 
[   28.276229] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE 
[   28.276911] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION 
[   28.277605] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION 
[   28.278302] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION 
[   28.279032] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION 
[   28.279752] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN 
[   28.280471] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID 
[   28.281195] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID 
[   28.281932] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   28.282671] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   28.283399] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM 
[   28.284153] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR 
[   28.285008] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired. 
[   28.285019] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   28.285809] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   28.620871] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=4, type=5 
[   28.620879] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=6, type=5 
[   29.995542] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5b00, CPU2 Status: 0x3 
[   29.995555] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80480218 
[   29.995564] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104 
[   29.995568] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired. 
[   29.995635] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   29.995638] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000010, count: 6 
[   29.995640] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode 
[   29.995642] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL     
[   29.995644] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0 
[   29.995646] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1 
[   29.995648] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004FA34A | branchlink2 
[   29.995650] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink1 
[   29.995652] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink2 
[   29.995654] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | data1 
[   29.995656] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2 
[   29.995658] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3 
[   29.995659] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time 
[   29.995661] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00007EB4 | tsf low 
[   29.995663] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi 
[   29.995665] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1 
[   29.995667] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000DAA8 | time gp2 
[   29.995669] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type 
[   29.995671] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | uCode version major 
[   29.995673] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | uCode version minor 
[   29.995674] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version 
[   29.995676] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version 
[   29.995678] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd 
[   29.995680] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0 
[   29.995682] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1 
[   29.995684] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2 
[   29.995686] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3 
[   29.995687] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4 
[   29.995689] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id 
[   29.995691] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | wait_event 
[   29.995693] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control 
[   29.995695] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration 
[   29.995697] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid 
[   29.995698] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match 
[   29.995700] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel 
[   29.995702] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp 
[   29.995704] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler 
[   29.995728] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   29.995730] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000010, count: 7 
[   29.995732] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x201000A3 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT 
[   29.995734] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1 
[   29.995736] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2 
[   29.995738] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0086AC0 | umac interruptlink1 
[   29.995740] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2 
[   29.995742] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1 
[   29.995744] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2 
[   29.995746] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3 
[   29.995747] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major 
[   29.995749] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor 
[   29.995751] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000DA9A | frame pointer 
[   29.995753] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886BF8 | stack pointer 
[   29.995755] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd 
[   29.995757] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg 
[   29.995763] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers: 
[   29.995766] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE 
[   29.995770] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION 
[   29.995774] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION 
[   29.995778] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION 
[   29.995782] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION 
[   29.995785] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN 
[   29.995789] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID 
[   29.995793] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID 
[   29.995796] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   29.995802] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   29.995808] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM 
[   29.995814] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR 
[   29.995819] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe! 
[   29.995822] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   29.995824] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   30.407259] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode (-2) 
[   30.407263] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2 
[   30.407771] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode 
[   30.407780] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver 
[   30.407790] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22 
[   30.407792] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM 
[   30.407793] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0 
[   30.408135] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm 
[   30.408155] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2) 
[   30.408172] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340 
[   30.585969] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: a8:7e:ea:ed:72:a9 
[   32.107530] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5b0c, CPU2 Status: 0x3 
[   32.107544] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80480218 
[   32.107555] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104 
[   32.107563] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired. 
[   32.107643] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   32.107646] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6 
[   32.107648] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode 
[   32.107661] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL     
[   32.107663] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0 
[   32.107665] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1 
[   32.107667] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004FA34A | branchlink2 
[   32.107669] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink1 
[   32.107671] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink2 
[   32.107673] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | data1 
[   32.107675] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2 
[   32.107677] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3 
[   32.107678] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time 
[   32.107680] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000B52A | tsf low 
[   32.107682] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi 
[   32.107684] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1 
[   32.107686] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0001112D | time gp2 
[   32.107688] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type 
[   32.107690] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | uCode version major 
[   32.107692] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | uCode version minor 
[   32.107694] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version 
[   32.107696] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version 
[   32.107698] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd 
[   32.107699] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0 
[   32.107701] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1 
[   32.107703] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2 
[   32.107705] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3 
[   32.107707] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4 
[   32.107709] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id 
[   32.107710] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | wait_event 
[   32.107712] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control 
[   32.107714] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration 
[   32.107716] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid 
[   32.107718] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match 
[   32.107720] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel 
[   32.107722] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp 
[   32.107724] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler 
[   32.107748] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   32.107750] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7 
[   32.107752] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT 
[   32.107754] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1 
[   32.107756] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2 
[   32.107758] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0086AC0 | umac interruptlink1 
[   32.107760] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2 
[   32.107762] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1 
[   32.107764] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2 
[   32.107766] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3 
[   32.107767] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major 
[   32.107769] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor 
[   32.107771] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0001111F | frame pointer 
[   32.107773] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886ADC | stack pointer 
[   32.107775] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd 
[   32.107777] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg 
[   32.107783] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers: 
[   32.107787] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE 
[   32.107790] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION 
[   32.107795] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION 
[   32.107801] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION 
[   32.107806] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION 
[   32.107811] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN 
[   32.107826] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID 
[   32.107831] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID 
[   32.107837] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   32.107844] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   32.107851] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM 
[   32.107856] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR 
[   32.107956] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired. 
[   32.107963] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   32.107966] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   32.442932] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=4, type=5 
[   32.442938] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Failed to dump region: id=6, type=5 
[   33.835557] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5a7f, CPU2 Status: 0x3 
[   33.835574] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80480218 
[   33.835584] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104 
[   33.835593] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired. 
[   33.835669] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   33.835672] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000010, count: 6 
[   33.835676] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode 
[   33.835680] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL     
[   33.835684] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0 
[   33.835687] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1 
[   33.835690] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004FA34A | branchlink2 
[   33.835693] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink1 
[   33.835696] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink2 
[   33.835699] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | data1 
[   33.835702] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2 
[   33.835705] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3 
[   33.835707] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time 
[   33.835709] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000B090 | tsf low 
[   33.835711] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi 
[   33.835713] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1 
[   33.835715] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00010C02 | time gp2 
[   33.835717] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type 
[   33.835719] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | uCode version major 
[   33.835721] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | uCode version minor 
[   33.835723] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version 
[   33.835724] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version 
[   33.835726] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd 
[   33.835728] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0 
[   33.835730] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1 
[   33.835732] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2 
[   33.835733] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3 
[   33.835735] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4 
[   33.835737] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id 
[   33.835739] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | wait_event 
[   33.835741] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control 
[   33.835743] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration 
[   33.835745] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid 
[   33.835747] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match 
[   33.835748] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel 
[   33.835750] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp 
[   33.835752] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler 
[   33.835777] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   33.835780] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000010, count: 7 
[   33.835782] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT 
[   33.835784] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1 
[   33.835786] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2 
[   33.835788] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0086AC0 | umac interruptlink1 
[   33.835791] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2 
[   33.835792] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1 
[   33.835794] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2 
[   33.835796] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3 
[   33.835798] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major 
[   33.835800] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor 
[   33.835802] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00010BF4 | frame pointer 
[   33.835804] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886ADC | stack pointer 
[   33.835806] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd 
[   33.835807] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg 
[   33.835814] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers: 
[   33.835818] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE 
[   33.835822] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION 
[   33.835826] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION 
[   33.835830] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION 
[   33.835834] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION 
[   33.835838] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN 
[   33.835842] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID 
[   33.835847] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID 
[   33.835851] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   33.835857] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   33.835865] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM 
[   33.835871] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR 
[   33.835877] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe! 
[   33.835882] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   33.835885] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   34.258401] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode (-2) 
[   34.258404] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2 
[   34.258835] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode 
[   34.258845] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver 
[   34.258854] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22 
[   34.258857] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM 
[   34.258858] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0 
[   34.259194] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm 
[   34.259203] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2) 
[   34.259222] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340 
[   35.307544] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5b48, CPU2 Status: 0x3 
[   35.307556] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80480218 
[   35.307565] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104 
[   35.307570] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired. 
[   35.307637] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   35.307639] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6 
[   35.307641] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode 
[   35.307644] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL     
[   35.307646] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0 
[   35.307648] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1 
[   35.307650] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004FA34A | branchlink2 
[   35.307652] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink1 
[   35.307654] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink2 
[   35.307656] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | data1 
[   35.307657] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2 
[   35.307659] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3 
[   35.307661] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time 
[   35.307663] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000B0C0 | tsf low 
[   35.307665] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi 
[   35.307667] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1 
[   35.307669] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00010CFB | time gp2 
[   35.307670] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type 
[   35.307672] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | uCode version major 
[   35.307674] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | uCode version minor 
[   35.307676] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version 
[   35.307678] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version 
[   35.307680] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd 
[   35.307682] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0 
[   35.307684] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1 
[   35.307686] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2 
[   35.307687] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3 
[   35.307689] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4 
[   35.307691] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id 
[   35.307693] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | wait_event 
[   35.307695] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control 
[   35.307697] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration 
[   35.307698] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid 
[   35.307700] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match 
[   35.307702] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel 
[   35.307704] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp 
[   35.307706] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler 
[   35.307730] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[   35.307732] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7 
[   35.307734] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT 
[   35.307736] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1 
[   35.307738] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2 
[   35.307740] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0086AC0 | umac interruptlink1 
[   35.307742] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2 
[   35.307744] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1 
[   35.307745] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2 
[   35.307747] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3 
[   35.307749] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major 
[   35.307751] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor 
[   35.307753] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00010CED | frame pointer 
[   35.307755] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886ADC | stack pointer 
[   35.307757] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd 
[   35.307758] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg 
[   35.307764] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers: 
[   35.307768] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE 
[   35.307772] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION 
[   35.307776] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION 
[   35.307780] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION 
[   35.307784] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION 
[   35.307787] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN 
[   35.307791] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID 
[   35.307795] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID 
[   35.307799] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   35.307804] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP 
[   35.307810] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM 
[   35.307816] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR 
[   35.307821] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110 
[   35.663630] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Comment: StackOverflow is designed to accumulate nice pairs of question and answer about software development. Your question is not related to software development so it is [off-topic at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and will be deleted sooner or later even in the case someone provides you with nice answer. You could try your chances at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) - I'm sure guys there will be willing to help you. By the way, does your motherboard has x1 slots? - try the card in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel you are using is 5.8 and the MAX microcode version supported in that kernel is iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
So you either you kernel to 5.11 or greater to support iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode
or use iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode or lower.

You can download find firmware from this link.
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/refs/

just download from the above link and extract it and copy the iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode to /lib/firmware and reboot.